Azure Pipelines Branch Name Evaluation
I have a section of my azure-pipelines.yml file here:
variables:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'branch1') }}:
    - group: variables-prod

  - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'branch2') }}: 
    - group: variables-test

  - ${{ else }}: 
    - group: variables-dev
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - branch1
    - branch2
    - branch3

For some reason, the evaluation on 'branch1' doesn't ever resolve to the correct branch. The evaluation on 'branch2' works fine. Just 'branch1'.
Is there a better way to do this, or can someone explain why the first evaluation never resolves to true?

Try elseif instead of if in 4th line:
replace
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'branch2') }}: 

with
- ${{ elseif eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'branch2') }}: 


Yeah this was the solution. It was staring me right in the face and I just missed it. Thanks!
